# How long it takes for the serial downvoting script to work? is it automatic?

Tags: support, down-votes, serial-voting

I suspect retaliation, 7 questions downvoted 5 hours ago, my question is about the serial downvoting script. Is it automatic? When does it kick in?

Comment: Link to some info on this is also in [serail-voting tag-wiki](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/serial-voting/info).

Comment: If I recall correctly, it runs at about 0300 zulu.

Comment: @T.Bongers thanks, hope it works, got another round today.

Comment: The serial voting script runs every day at 3:00 UTC time: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me

Comment: @emcor I think that your comment could be expanded to an answer.

Comment: thanks I did.. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The serial voting script runs every day at 3:00 UTC time: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

All other information on the script is secret to avoid abuse of possibly hiding serial votes from the algorithm.

Comment: Just to save people some time zone calculations, 3:00 UTC when the serial voting script runs is 8pm San Francisco (PDT) or 11pm New York (EDT), 4am London, 5am Paris, Munich and Rome, 6am Moscow, 7am most of India, 10am most of China, 12 noon Sydney and Tokyo.  All times stated during daylight savings time - adjust accordingly for your region.